# Xamarin.forms How to Change TableSection Title Color

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am working on **Xamarin.forms** PCL Project, I am searching away to Change `TextColor` for the title of `TableSection`

```
<TableView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  IsVisible="false" HasUnevenRows="true">
        <TableRoot>
          <TableSection Title="Order Information" >
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Created" TextColor="Silver" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Created}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" TextColor="Navy" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
    </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
      </TableView>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried the solution form Xamarin Forum with Custom Renderers like this: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32379/changing-the-title-color-of-a-tablesection

Comment: not good enough solution , but i hope some one give us solution for all platforms

Comment: I agree with that

Comment: i am  trying to change the default color, any idea?

Comment: By checking the souce code of the [TableSection](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/TableSectionBase.cs) there is only one property `title`. I think custom render is the only way to change the color. You can refer to the [xamarin government forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32379/changing-the-title-color-of-a-tablesection)

Comment: My suggestion would be to abandon TableView! Jason Smith ( from Xamarin ) stressed this in last years evolve ( http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips ) to not use it anymore. You should be able to have same look and feel with listview, even with more control on how you would like the styling.

Comment: @Depechie thanks for this inof, but i have alot of tablesection on my project :(

Comment: For android project, you can simply change it in the style as: ' <item name="colorAccent">@color/PrimaryColor</item>'